# Fetch nested vales from JSON - python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I have a code as below, I need **status** and **policy workflow name** (i.e. Tuesday) as well in the output with below 2 conditions-

1- if clientHostname matches xyz remove that line
2- if status is [Aborted] changed it to [Failed]

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import ast
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', 100)

a = [{'attributes': [{'key': '*policy action jobid', 'values': ['289903']}, {'key': '*policy action name', 'values': ['backup']}, {'key': '*policy name', 'values': ['Daily_Backups']}, {'key': '*policy workflow name', 'values': ['tuesday']}, {'key': 'clone retention policy', 'values': ['   504:   5:  34']}, {'key': 'group', 'values': ['tuesday']}, {'key': 'saveset features', 'values': ['CLIENT_SAVETIME']}], 'browseTime': '2020-05-19T23:57:41+08:00', 'clientHostname': 'xyz.com', 'clientId': '7d391c52-00000004-5cda459d-5c1', 'creationTime': '2020-04-28T21:29:25+08:00', 'fileCount': 0, 'id': '1eb1', 'instances': [], 'level': 'Full', 'links': [{'href': 'https://iservera/backups/1ec1', 'rel': 'item'}], 'name': '/abc', 'retentionTime': '2020-05-19T23:57:41+08:00', 'saveTime': '2020-04-28T21:27:07+08:00', 'shortId': '2177', 'size': {'unit': 'Byte', 'value': 0}, 'type': 'File'}, {'attributes': [{'key': '*policy action jobid', 'values': ['2803']}, {'key': '*policy action name', 'values': ['backup: 1589']}, {'key': '*policy name', 'values': ['Daily_Backups: 159']}, {'key': '*policy workflow name', 'values': ['tuesday: 1588079529']}, {'key': '*ss clone retention', 'values': ['          1588079529:          1588079590:   1824409']}, {'key': 'group', 'values': ['tuesday']}, {'key': 'saveset features', 'values': ['CLIENT_SAVETIME']}], 'browseTime': '2020-05-19T23:57:42+08:00', 'clientHostname': 'abc.com', 'clientId': 'ec3dc1', 'completionTime': '2020-04-28T21:29:47+08:00', 'creationTime': '2020-04-28T21:13:10+08:00', 'fileCount': 0, 'id': 'cc1', 'instances': [{'clone': False, 'id': '1588079529', 'status': 'Aborted', 'volumeIds': ['245614341']}], 'level': 'Full', 'links': [{'href': 'https://abc/backups/c771', 'rel': 'item'}], 'name': '/xyz', 'retentionTime': '2020-05-19T23:57:42+08:00', 'saveTime': '2020-04-28T21:10:53+08:00', 'shortId': '2141727718', 'size': {'unit': 'Byte', 'value': 36264099844}, 'type': 'NDMP'}]
df = json_normalize(a)
a = df[['clientHostname','completionTime','size.value','type','fileCount']]
print(a)
```

Current output is:

```
clientHostname             completionTime   size.value  type  fileCount
0        xyz.com                        NaN            0  File          0
1        abc.com  2020-04-28T21:29:47+08:00  36264099844  NDMP          0
```

Expected Output is:

```
clientHostname             completionTime   size.value  type  fileCount  status Policy
1        abc.com  2020-04-28T21:29:47+08:00  36264099844  NDMP          0 [Failed] tuesday
```

Comment: please add output expected to be clear

Comment: Expected output attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'll make use of a library [jmespath](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py) to traverse the json data :

to access a key, use `.`; to access a list use the `[]` notation.

```
import jmespath
expression = jmespath.compile("""
                              [].
                               {clientHostname:clientHostname,
                                completionTime:completionTime,
                                "size.value":size.value,
                                type:type,
                                fileCount:fileCount,
                                status:instances[].status,
                                Policy:attributes[?key==`*policy workflow name`].values[]}
                               """)
res = expression.search(a)
res

[{'clientHostname': 'xyz.com',
  'completionTime': None,
  'size.value': 0,
  'type': 'File',
  'fileCount': 0,
  'status': [],
  'Policy': ['tuesday']},
 {'clientHostname': 'abc.com',
  'completionTime': '2020-04-28T21:29:47+08:00',
  'size.value': 36264099844,
  'type': 'NDMP',
  'fileCount': 0,
  'status': ['Aborted'],
  'Policy': ['tuesday: 1588079529']}]
```

make some cleanups to fit ur use case :

```
new = []
for entry in res:
    if "xyz" in entry['clientHostname'] :
        continue
    new.append(entry)

for ent in new:
    ent['Policy'] = ent['Policy'][0].split(':')[0]
    if ent['status'] == ["Aborted"]:
        ent['status'] = ["Failed"]

new

[{'clientHostname': 'abc.com',
  'completionTime': '2020-04-28T21:29:47+08:00',
  'size.value': 36264099844,
  'type': 'NDMP',
  'fileCount': 0,
  'status': ['Failed'],
  'Policy': 'tuesday'}]

 pd.DataFrame(new)


    clientHostname  completionTime  size.value  type    fileCount   status  Policy
0   abc.com 2020-04-28T21:29:47+08:00   36264099844 NDMP    0   [Failed]    tuesday
```

you might have to look at your data and see if there are other transformations u need to make

Comment: and suppose if i want to remove all the rows where clientHostname starts with xyz, can that also be done?

Comment: u can do a dictionary comprehension to filter out entries where ```clientHostname == "xyz.com"```

Comment: I tried but no luck, could you  please help with the code.

Comment: kindly post ur expected output

Comment: I am trying {name:[name == 'xyz.com'] but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: so suppose if in the  i only want servers which has xyz in it, so output should be-

clientHostname  completionTime  size.value  type    fileCount   status  Policy
0   xyz.com None    0   File    0   -   tuesday

Comment: there is no expected output in ur question

Comment: If clientHostname has xyz in it, remove the complete line, expected output below

clientHostname  completionTime  size.value  type    fileCount   status  Policy
1   abc.com 2020-04-28T21:29:47+08:00   36264099844 NDMP    0   [Aborted]   tuesday

Comment: Also if we wanted to replace all [Aborted] in the output with [Failed], Can you please help with it.

Comment: edit ur original question and add ur expected output. it allows anybody new to ur question to understand what u want and appropriately answer

Comment: I have edited my original question, can you please help now.

Comment: edited the code. test and see if it works on ur data

Comment: My question was if clientHostname  has xyz in it, it should ignore that line but in this case you have provided the full vaue "xyz.com" , there are chances that my server name would be xyz123.com, anyway it is doing what it should do..Thanks for your help, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to fetch **policy workflow name** as `df['attributes'][0][3]['key']`, `df['attributes'][0][3]['values']`
and **status** as `df['instances'][**i**][0]['status']`, where **i** is the record number.

**Try this:**

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', 100)

a = [{'attributes': [{'key': '*policy action jobid', 'values': ['289903']}, {'key': '*policy action name', 'values': ['backup']}, {'key': '*policy name', 'values': ['Daily_Backups']}, {'key': '*policy workflow name', 'values': ['tuesday']}, {'key': 'clone retention policy', 'values': ['   504:   5:  34']}, {'key': 'group', 'values': ['tuesday']}, {'key': 'saveset features', 'values': ['CLIENT_SAVETIME']}], 'browseTime': '2020-05-19T23:57:41+08:00', 'clientHostname': 'xyz.com', 'clientId': '7d391c52-00000004-5cda459d-5c1', 'creationTime': '2020-04-28T21:29:25+08:00', 'fileCount': 0, 'id': '1eb1', 'instances': [], 'level': 'Full', 'links': [{'href': 'https://iservera/backups/1ec1', 'rel': 'item'}], 'name': '/abc', 'retentionTime': '2020-05-19T23:57:41+08:00', 'saveTime': '2020-04-28T21:27:07+08:00', 'shortId': '2177', 'size': {'unit': 'Byte', 'value': 0}, 'type': 'File'}, {'attributes': [{'key': '*policy action jobid', 'values': ['2803']}, {'key': '*policy action name', 'values': ['backup: 1589']}, {'key': '*policy name', 'values': ['Daily_Backups: 159']}, {'key': '*policy workflow name', 'values': ['tuesday: 1588079529']}, {'key': '*ss clone retention', 'values': ['          1588079529:          1588079590:   1824409']}, {'key': 'group', 'values': ['tuesday']}, {'key': 'saveset features', 'values': ['CLIENT_SAVETIME']}], 'browseTime': '2020-05-19T23:57:42+08:00', 'clientHostname': 'abc.com', 'clientId': 'ec3dc1', 'completionTime': '2020-04-28T21:29:47+08:00', 'creationTime': '2020-04-28T21:13:10+08:00', 'fileCount': 0, 'id': 'cc1', 'instances': [{'clone': False, 'id': '1588079529', 'status': 'Aborted', 'volumeIds': ['245614341']}], 'level': 'Full', 'links': [{'href': 'https://abc/backups/c771', 'rel': 'item'}], 'name': '/xyz', 'retentionTime': '2020-05-19T23:57:42+08:00', 'saveTime': '2020-04-28T21:10:53+08:00', 'shortId': '2141727718', 'size': {'unit': 'Byte', 'value': 36264099844}, 'type': 'NDMP'}]
df = pd.json_normalize(a)
status = []
policy = []
for attribute in df['attributes']:
    policy.append(attribute[3]['values'])

for instance in df['instances']:
    if len(instance) == 0:
        status.append('-')
    else:
        for i in instance:
            status.append(i['status'])
a = df[['clientHostname','completionTime','size.value','type','fileCount']]
a.insert(5, 'policy', policy)
a.insert(6, 'status', status)
```

also pandas.io.json.json_normalize is deprecated, use pandas.json_normalize instead

Comment: Can you please help it in the code, I guess by this it would only print once instance of it.

Comment: actually, you are trying to create a dataframe from nested JSON( you can see that better if you try to print the whole df in jupyter notebook - the attrbute field has the whole lists). So to get the desired output, you can create another resultant dataframe which will be filled by iterating over your current dataframe. I can help you with the code if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the format of the attributes and instances dictionaries remain constant throughout the dataframe:

```
a = raw_json
df_temp = json_normalize(a)
```

Create a list of statuses and policy workflow names

```
statuses = [i[0]['status']if len(i)>0 else np.nan for i in df_temp['instances']]
policy_workflow_names = [i[3]['values'] if len(i)>0 else np.nan for i in df_temp['attributes']]
```

It is important that the format of the values in the attributes and the instances column remain constant or this will not work.

Once your have these two lists, put them in your final dataframe.

```
a = df[['clientHostname','completionTime','size.value','type','fileCount']]
a['policy workflow name'] = policy_workflow_names
a['statuses'] = statuses
```